# What is the datetime format for flask-restful parser?

Tags: python, datetime, flask, flask-restful

Let's say that I have following parser inside my get method:

```
from flask.ext.restful import reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('when', type=datetime, help='Input wasn\'t valid!')
```

And then I want to test the said get method with curl...

```
curl --data "when=[WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?]" localhost:5000/myGet
```

So the question is, how I should call the get method? I've tried numerous different formats, tried to read rfc228 standard, etc. but I can't figure out the right format.

Comment: I just noticed that documentation on flask-restful web page seems to be ahead on it's time and therefore it's possible that the datetime parser hasn't been implemented yet (I'm using version 0.2.12). I can't say for sure.

Comment: If you are following documentation, then it might be for the latest build which is not yet in pip, You can clone the github project and check if the problem persist.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Kinda late, but I've just been in the same problem, trying to parse a datetime with RequestParser, and sadly the docs are not so helpful for this scenario, so after seeing and testing RequestParser and Argument code, I think I found the problem:

When you use `type=datetime` in the `add_argument` method, under the hood it just calls `datetime` with the arg, like this: `datetime(arg)`, so if your param is a string like this: `2016-07-12T23:13:3`, the error will be `an integer is required`.

In my case, I wanted to parse a string with this format `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S` into a datetime object, so I thought to use something like `type=datetime.strptime` but as you know this method needs a format parameter, so I finally used this workaround:

`parser.add_argument('date', type=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))`

As you can see in this way you can use whatever format datetime you want. Also you can use `partial` functool instead of lambda to get the same result or a named function.

This workaround is [in the docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html#inputs).

Answer (score 7):

Just an **update** on Flask-Restful (0.3.5): it is possible to use the own library date and datetime functionality parsing, if ISO 8601 or RFC 822 suffices:

```
from flask_restful import inputs

parser.add_argument('date', type=inputs.datetime_from_iso8601)
```

So the request would be,

```
curl --data "date=2012-01-01T23:30:00+02:00" localhost:5000/myGet
```

From [the docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#inputs)